# Maven Multiple Local Repository

Tags: maven, apache-servicemix

I have multiple Maven project in my Local, by default maven repository in my local is at ~/.m2/repository.

Now I wanted to create different maven repository for each Maven project.

i.e.

> 1. Maven Project 1 = ~/.m2/repository
> 2. Maven Project 2 = ~/.m3/repository
> 3. Maven Project 3 = ~/.m3/repository

Edit: I am using Servicemix as a container.

Comment: Hi.  This is quite ambiguous : I don't understand if you need to have 2 projects on the same repository or if you need to have one repository per project. What is your exact question ?

Comment: I need one repository per project.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the path to the local repository in your maven `settings.xml` configuration file: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Maven settings.xml which is under maven/conf folder, there you will find tag localRepository, you need to modify it accordingly, default value is 
**${user.home}/.m2/repository**

but Maven create repository one at a time that means for each project you need to change your settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be new configuration option, not very well documented, hinted at in https://maven.apache.org/resolver/local-repository.html that allows for repository splitting.

```
$ mvn ... -Daether.enhancedLocalRepository.split \
          -Daether.enhancedLocalRepository.localPrefix=maven-resolver/mresolver-253
          -Daether.enhancedLocalRepository.splitRemoteRepository
```

The localPrefix is what I think you are looking for.

You will need least Maven 3.9.0